# Windows Defender last run result shows 0x2 - on Windows 10, Version 1709, OS Build 16299.192

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-defender

Not sure why my Windows Defender Scheduled Scan showed 0x2 in the Last Run Result. Did not really bother to check the last run result as it has been running behind the scene nicely and quietly without bothering me in the past.

But few days back just updated windows to Version 1709 and wanted to start fiddle with scheduled scan. Come to realize 0x2 is shown. However the windows defender security centre every statuses are good and green as always.

Any idea why 0x2, and is it a problem? If so, how to resolve?

Comment: 0x2 = ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: thanks. I am aware the 0x2 message is error file not found. and have checked the program file that the scheduled task is pointing to, it is still there.

Comment: you asked what 0x2 is and I told you it. so why do you ask? use **Process monitor** from sysinternals to see which operation cause File not found message